# connections are abort while uploading big files

Tags: php, linux, file-upload

Sometimes (the changes are 75%) connections are abort while uploading big files (100MB or so). Files are uploaded via ajax. Have the code below already and safe mode is disabled. Webserver is XAMPP for Linux (CentOS 5.5).

```
  ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '512M');
  ini_set('post_max_size', '512M');
  ini_set('memory_limit', '1G');
  set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: upload_max_filesize is 512M and you uploading 1000 MB. Is it possible? :)

Comment: @above - If there is no enough disk space, how can a retry be successful? And it is 100 MB not 1000 MB :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `memory_limit` with `GB` not `G`like this

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1GB');
```

Test if setting is setted with

```
var_dump(ini_get('memory_limit'));
```

And maybe there are some timeout's. Look at this page: [www.caiapps.com/max_execution_time-vs-default_socket_timeout](http://www.caiapps.com/max_execution_time-vs-default_socket_timeout/)

Comment: what if the var_dump test is unsuccessful? I have tried this way but no change.

Comment: I think there are some server options to forbid this changes. Have you asked your provider for some limitations?